# Is it possible to run a Powershell on a remote server using power automate online?

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2, power-automate, powerapps, ms-forms

I want to have an MS Form to get users to make a selection and have these selection values sent over to a Powershell variable in an AWS EC2 instance and have it executed there.

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a power automate to send over the variable values and have it trigger this Powershell script on submit.

Comment: Yes, it’s possible.